# How to back up acl to file then apply this to another folder?

Tags: linux, centos, acl, rhel

Backup "myfolder" folder's permission with getfacl and apply those permissions to "/yourfolder" directory.

```
              getfacl file1 | setfacl --set-file=- file2
```

code above does not suite for me as I need 2 different commands

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty much the same.

```
getfacl /myfolder | setfacl --set-file=- /yourfolder
```

You can backup the folder's permission like so:

```
getfacl /myfolder > myfolder_acl_backup
setfacl --set-file=myfolder_acl_backup /yourfolder
```